# Impersonation is not working with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, impersonation

i am trying to impersonate another user before running a connecting to an API.  my code has worked fine on windows xp, but 1 user received a windows 7 machine and the code no longer works.  there is no error, imperonsation seems to be working, but no matter what I try the service is called using the current user's context.   I have tried turning down UAC, still nothing.  if I Run AS I can get the entire application to run as the other user, but this is not what I want to do.  Anyone know what could cause impersonation to stop working on a machine?

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;


  //This class is based on the code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-      us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx
//And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx
public class Impersonator
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

    //For reference, not used yet.  
    //Ex: (int)Logontype.Interactive
    enum LogonType
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network = 3,
        Batch = 4,
        Service = 5,
        Unlock = 7,
        NetworkClearText = 8,
        NewCredentials = 9
    }

    //For reference, not used yet
    enum LogonProvider
    {
        Default = 0,
        WinNT35 = 1,
        WinNT40 = 2,
    }

    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Impersonate(string user, string domain, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //Impersonate a Windows User
            SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle = default(SafeTokenHandle);

            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

            //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token. 
            //const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2; //Orig
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2; //2,9,7

            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token. 
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(user, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);

            WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity    (safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
            impersonationContext = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();

            //WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void StopImpersonating()
    {
        try
        {
            // Stop impersonating the user.
            impersonationContext.Undo();

            // Check the identity name.
            Console.Write("Name of the identity after performing an Undo on the");
            Console.WriteLine(" impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;

public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```